# Ubuntu install to VM

Tags: virtualbox

I want to install Ubuntu to the oracle virtual machine.
My computer has windows 10
I set up Ubuntu in the virtual machine and ran the ISO and it went to 100% disk checking. I got to the point where it says to try unbuntu or install it. I choose install. the first option is the installation type and it says no detected operating systems and a warning underneath saying this will delete all programs etc. If I choose erase disk and install ubuntu.
What happens if I choose this option will it wipe my entire computer?

I click on the option - something else - (to see if thats a better option) but when I tried to install from there it says no root file system is defined.

Comment: What happens in the virtual machine stays in the virtual machine.

Comment: Make absolutely sure you are in the VM before proceeding with any decision - is the screen you are seeing full screen or in a window?  Can you take a screenshot and show us?

Answer (score 14):

Erase disk will only erase the virtual disk you set up when you created the virtual machine. If you've previously installed a different operating system on that same virtual machine you will be erasing it and all it's files, but if that's a new virtual machine then you're all good.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer above this said, Erase the drive is the best option.

If you are using a virtual machine, it is impossible (unless you have network sharing, or virtualbox guest additions) to interact with the host computer in any way, and especially if you have a VPN.

So you will not lose anything but potential operating systems on the virtual machine's hard drive. Your files are completely safe.

One of my hobbies personally is to go around in a Windows 7 or Windows 10 virtual machine and try to get as many viruses as possible. None of them have ever caused a problem on a real computer in this house, especially since I use a VPN.

Comment: _"and especially if you have a VPN"_ - can you elaborate how a VPN affects VM's ability to interact with the host?

Comment: If you download viruses for instance without a VPN, the virus can get your IP and hack your computer from the virus's server

Comment: If you've downloaded a virus, then the computer is already compromised, there's no reason to "hack" it. The virus can connect wherever it wants even through your VPN. Most of the claims done by VPN ads are just lies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry. That warning only exists to warn people that have actual drives with stuff in them who want to install Ubuntu. The same menu where you are at in the installation is where people can set up to have their machines with multiple partitions with different operating systems if they feel like it.

Given that you're setting up Ubuntu in a virtual machine, you have absolutely nothing to worry about. Just select the default option and say yes after it gives you the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new VM.

Installing a new OS on an existing VM is a pain; it's much easier to just make a new VM (provided you have enough storage space on your computer).

Comment: This message pops up every time, no matter if the VM (or a physical computer) is clean or not.